# SELECT WHERE statement in a JOIN

Tags: t-sql

I'm trying to make a query with a SELECT statement in a JOIN but couldn't get it to work.

The tables I have are below :

```
CREATE TABLE check_result
    (id int,
    check_result_id int,
    id_relation int);
    
INSERT INTO check_result
    values(1, 12, 1), (2,9, 1),(3,13, 3);
    
CREATE TABLE relation
    (id int,
    name VARCHAR(20),
    id_group int);
    
INSERT INTO relation
    values(1, 'pietje', 1), (2,'klaasje', 1),(3,'Harry', 3);

CREATE TABLE groups
    (id int,
    name VARCHAR(20),
    id_sub int);
    
INSERT INTO groups
  values(1, 'support_worker 1',2),(2, 'support_worker 2',2),(3, 'support_worker 2',3);
```

The query I have thus far is something like :

```
SELECT R.name , G.name
FROM check_result CR
    LEFT JOIN relation R ON R.id = CR.id_relation
    LEFT JOIN groups G ON R.id_group = (SELECT id_sub 
                                        FROM groups 
                                        WHERE name = 'support_worker 2' 
                                        AND id_sub = R.id_group )
```

In the end I was hoping for 3 records in the results but instead there are 6, with the correct results from groups.

Is there somebody who can show me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Can you add what exactly you're expected results would be in a table format?

Comment: 'support_worker 2' record is duplicate in groups table with ID 2 & 3

Comment: What is the output you are hoping to achieve? If you can tell us what you're hoping to get in terms of rows/columns/values, that will help us with giving you the appropriate query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With that dataset and without your expected results it is hard to give you a solid answer.

```
    SELECT R.name , G.name
    FROM check_result CR
    LEFT JOIN relation R ON R.id = CR.id_relation
    LEFT JOIN groups G ON G.id_sub = R.id_group and G.name = 'support_worker 2'
```

You mentioned wanting all 3 results, but your sub select was causing duplicate records to appear.

Is it not a case as the above of not needing to rely on the sub select and simply adding more conditions onto your left join?

One additional thing worth mentioning - as I have little knowledge on what you database structure is but if Groups has an Id that is being references in **R.id_group** then you should join that and not **Id_sub** which would change your code to be:

```
    SELECT R.name , G.name
    FROM check_result CR
    LEFT JOIN relation R ON R.id = CR.id_relation
    LEFT JOIN groups G ON G.id = R.id_group and G.name = 'support_worker 2'
```

Giving the same result in the limited data.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5dbadf/14)

Comment: thanks, this totaly helps!!! also helped me in understanding ...